# Angular equivalent of ko.utils.arrayFirst()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js

Knockout utilities have some neat array filtering tools that I can't seem to find built in with angular.

In knockout, I would do this:

```
ko.utils.arrayFirst(myArray, function(item){
    return item.property === criteria;
});
```

In angular, I am currently using this:

```
for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
    if (myArray[x].property === criteria){
         return myArray[x];
         break;
    }
 }
```

I understand that I could also use `angular.forEach` here, but I am looking for something similar to the `arrayFirst` with Knockout.  I also know how to write the as a helper in Angular, I just want to know if it is built in already.

Comment: If you only have to support the latest browsers you can also use `Array.prototype.find`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simple filtering of an array can help:

```
var foundItem = myArray.filter(function(item) { return item.property === criteia; })[0];
```

"foundItem" will be undefined if nothing was found.

Comment: Yep, this works just fine.  I am not a huge fan of throwing the `[0]` on the end there, I feel this makes it a little more difficult to read, as it is easily missed.  That is just an opinion though

Answer (score 1):

How about using AngularJs [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) function?

```
var filtered = $filter('filter')(myArray, { property: criteria });
var item = filtered.shift();
```